# Why are featured images sometimes cropped, and sometimes not

Tags: images

I am developing a website using Wordpress CMS, in particular Hatch theme. I noticed that in some posts, featured image is displayed full size (like [here](http://vetrerianovart.it/gioielli-in-vetro/)) but in others, featured image has a smaller size, cropping the original image,[image: small featured image] 
[image]
I don't think it is about image starting size, because some of the images displayed correctly are way bigger than the one it shows as cropped. Both of them are made with cameras. Moreover, if I change the freshly updated photo with another one that i recently uploaded, it shows as cropped, while changing it with older photos shows it full size

Do you know why it behaves like this, and how I can fix it? Can it be an extension issue (even though they both are JPEGs)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image sizes are generated when the original is uploaded. If you add an image size after files have already been uploaded, those old images won't have the new sizes, and will default to displaying the original. If you [search the WordPress Plugin repository for "regenerate images"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=regenerate+images) you'll find some plugins that will simplify fixing this.

Comment: But if I regenerate images, it would make all of them crop when set as thumbnail, and I don't want it

Comment: the size you ultimately see is controlled by your template. if you want an uncropped version, you either need to re-register the image size to be uncropped, or change which image size is being used when the image is output.